# "author?" error using natbib

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am trying to import citations but the following error occurs. It displays **author?** instead of `author-year`.

`document1.snw`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{natbib}



\begin{document}

the possible future events \citet{Test12}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References_trial}

\end{document}
```

`References_trial.bib`:

```
@article{Test12,
    author = {{John Smith}},
    title = {Test Article},
    year = {2012},
    journal = {The Test Journal}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: plese don't use the tag `biblatex` when this is not related to `biblatex` as you don't use it.

Comment: That is not the output I get. Did you compile enough times? `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`

Comment: @daleif I am using knit for the  document1.snw in RStudio and after that I compile document1.tex . The method that i have used to complite it, is the method that you described above.

Comment: Are you sure, you're compiling the right files? Compiling your example gives me the desired output. Yet, the References aren't numbered. So there is something else going on here.

Comment: @phil-elkabat It works for me also using a sample `file.tex`. However, i am using `.snw` format. Does this affect the citations?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with knitr and the R-side of LaTeX. Surely somebody else will be able to help.

Comment: Why do you enclose John Smith in curly braces, i.e. as `author = {{John Smith}}` instead of `author = {John Smith}`? I think you try to use this to get the name as "John Smith" instead of "Smith, John" or "Smith, J.". However, if that is the case, use a reference style that gives you the name in the desired format. Because if you do it like that and ever want to use a reference style in author-year format with alphabetically ordered bibliography, this will wreak havoc. BibTeX will be unable to determine first and last names and will sort "John Smith" before "Zac Ahrens", for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments and observations:

- If you want to use `\citet` to generate "textual style" authoryear-type citation call-outs, be sure to load the `natbib` citation package with the options `authoryear` and `round`.
- Whatever else you do, change `author = {{John Smith}},` to either `author = {John Smith},` or `author = {Smith, John},`.
- Be sure to run a full compile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to resolve the `\cite`-related cross-dependencies.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{References_trial.bib}
@article{Test25,
    author = {John Smith},
    title  = {Test Article},
    journal= {The Test Journal},
    year   = {2525},
    volume = {1},
    number = {2},
    pages  = {3-4},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{Test25}
\bibliography{References_trial}
\end{document}
```